# How to place the navigation bar under the header 1

Tags: html, css

I want to make a html like this:
[image]

I have completed the following parts:
[image]

Now, the problem is, if I want to place the "Home About Us...." navigation bar, I only can place it in this inapporiate location instead of under the "Art Store"(I have tried`div`method.), 
[image]
so how to place the navigation bar under the "Art Store"?

**HTML**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Assignment 1 - Page 1</title>

   <link href="reset.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="assign1.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>
<body>
<div class="navTop">
        <a href="#">My Account</a>
        <a href="#">Wish List</a>
        <a href="#">Shopping Cart</a>
        <a href="#">Checkout</a>
    </div>
<div class="page1Tile">
    <h1>Art&nbsp;Store</h1>
</div>
<div class="page1SubNav">
    <ul>
    <li>NMSL</li>
    <li>CNM</li>
    </ul>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
   font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 1.428571429;
   color: #333333;
    background-image: url(images/stucco/stucco_@2X.png)
}

.navTop {
  height: calc( 40px + (50 - 40) * ( (100vw - 400px) / ( 800 - 400) ));
  line-height: calc( 40px + (50 - 40) * ( (100vw - 400px) / ( 800 - 400) ));
  background:black;
  margin: -8px -8px 0 -8px;

}

.navTop a {
  margin-right: 4ex;
  color: grey;
  font-family: 'Calluna Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: calc(6px + (18 - 12) * ( (100vw - 400px) / ( 800 - 400) ));
  text-decoration: none;
  float:right
}

.page1Tile{
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 60px;
    float:left;
}

.page1SubNav nav{
    float:left;
}

.page1SubNav {
    height: calc( 40px + (50 - 40) * ( (100vw - 400px) / ( 800 - 400) ));
  line-height: calc( 40px + (50 - 40) * ( (100vw - 400px) / ( 800 - 400) ));
  background:white;
  margin: -8px -8px 0 -8px;
}

.page1SubNav li{
    float:left;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.page1SubNav li a{
    display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: The 'home', 'about us', etc are not in your html

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
   font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 1.428571429;
   color: #333333;
    background-image: url(images/stucco/stucco_@2X.png)
}

.navTop {
  height: calc( 40px + (50 - 40) * ( (100vw - 400px) / ( 800 - 400) ));
  line-height: calc( 40px + (50 - 40) * ( (100vw - 400px) / ( 800 - 400) ));
  background:black;
  margin: -8px -8px 0 -8px;

}

.navTop a {
  margin-right: 4ex;
  color: grey;
  font-family: 'Calluna Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: calc(6px + (18 - 12) * ( (100vw - 400px) / ( 800 - 400) ));
  text-decoration: none;
  float:right
}

.page1Tile{
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 60px;
    
}

.page1SubNav nav{
    float:left;
}

.page1SubNav {
    height: calc( 40px + (50 - 40) * ( (100vw - 400px) / ( 800 - 400) ));
  line-height: calc( 40px + (50 - 40) * ( (100vw - 400px) / ( 800 - 400) ));
  background:white;
  margin: -8px -8px 0 -8px;
}

.page1SubNav li{
    float:left;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.page1SubNav li a{
    display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="navTop">
        <a href="#">My Account</a>
        <a href="#">Wish List</a>
        <a href="#">Shopping Cart</a>
        <a href="#">Checkout</a>
    </div>
<div class="page1Tile">
    <h1>Art&nbsp;Store</h1>
</div>
<div class="page1SubNav">
    <ul>
    <li>NMSL</li>
    <li>CNM</li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

Removing `float:left` from `.page1Tile` should make it work

Float left makes sure that the width of the div is based on the content. So the content below Art store moves up and overlaps